# Does secure boot prevent evil maid attacks when using LUKS?

Tags: luks, debian, secure-boot

When one installs Debian 11 with secure-boot enabled, is computer protected against evil maid attacks trying to capture encryption keys using software keylogger?

Disk is formatted using defaults which means boot partition is not encrypted.

Thanks for helping out!